# Load complete javascript to Web Url before the web page is loaded in Android webview

Tags: android

I am trying to inject the javascript library to webview from outside in onPageStarted() and onPageFinished() using loadUrl("javascript: the javascript string"). 
Basically the $(document).ready(function() function needs the javascript library to be available before $(document).ready(function() is getting called.
It is observed the $(document).ready(function() is getting called before the library are completely injected to the webview.

**Is there a way where I can force the $(document).ready(function() to be triggered from webview after the library is injected to the webview**

**Please suggest how can I load the library before the $(document).ready(function() is being called or how can I delay the call to $(document).ready(function() of the webpage. 
I have implemented the javainterface where i get a call for the library completely being loaded.**

Answer (score 0):

you have to download the page using http basic request, add the

```
<SCRIPT language="Javascript">
```

javascript path on device

```
</SCRIPT>
```

then load the html file by your web view .

Comment: The weburl also has css and other related assets like images...etc...that will be very cumbersome and the assets are not embedded in the html, they are at relative path...